# How do I get the it to accept the input (1) and make it print the if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, input

```
def user_input():
    user_input = input


name = input("enter your name ")
print("hello "+ name +"!")
print("welcome to gymbros press 1 to continue :")
if input == 1():
    print("this is the personal record page where you post your best lifts ")
else: 
    print("thanks for using gymbros")
```

####################################
Im not sure what im doing wrong it keeps giving me the, TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  ```1()``` is invalid.  Did you mean to do ```if input() == "1":```? Please clarify what it is you're doing.

Comment: You already know how to get a users input and save it to a variable, you do that 3 lines above, now you just need to compare it to a `"1"`

Comment: what you want to do with this statement? 
if input == 1():

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many things in this code that don't make sense. Please try to find and follow a Python tutorial all the way through, to learn the fundamentals. Also: please read [ask], and please only use tags that you expect are *relevant to the problem*. For example, only tag your IDE if you think that the problem is caused in part by the IDE.

Comment: @ewong if input() == "1":  yes this is what I'm trying to do

Comment: if input("welcome to gymbros press 1 to continue :") == 1:
        print("this is the personal record page where you post your best lifts ")
    else:
        print("thanks for using gymbros")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` return type is str and int is not callable.
`user_input` is not used
It is recommended that you learn the basic syntax of Python first

```
name = input("enter your name ")
print("hello", name, "!")
print("welcome to gymbros press 1 to continue :")
if input() == "1":
    print("this is the personal record page where you post your best lifts ")
else:
    print("thanks for using gymbros")
```